# How solve deleted file issue after merging?

Tags: github

I am working on development branch now I checkout to main branch using command

```
git checkout main
```

and i merge development branch using command

```
git merge development
```

But now some files are deleted. No conflict occur.
How I can solve this issue
[image]

Comment: The deletion does not appear to be something that Git did.

Comment: But I see this after merging

Comment: Yes, but "after" does not mean Git did it. In fact Git is apparently telling you that you deleted the files and is asking you if you want to commit that deletion. If the merge had deleted the files, Git would not remark on them; they would just be gone.

Comment: Anyway were these files part of the earlier commit? If so you could just undo the merge.

Comment: I dont know what's hppend. I again add file and push now its working thanks

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what's hppend. I again add file and push now its working thanks